# Access website by multiple domain names only (no IP)

Tags: networking, server, apache2, domain-server

With the code below I only allow people to visit my website by one domain. I need multidomain support like example.com and example2.com. How to do this?

```
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
   UseCanonicalName Off
   <If "tolower(%{SERVER_NAME}) != 'example.com'">
      AllowOverride None
      Require all denied
   </If>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `ServerAlias`:

```
ServerAlias example2.com example3.net
```

You can also use wildcards:

```
ServerAlias example2.com *.org *.net
```

If you want a “catch-all”, use `*.*`